# Container IP resolution not working for Windows containers in docker compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, dns

I am using Docker compose with Windows containers and I want to be able to establish connections between the containers within my solution using their container names.

My understanding is that, within a Docker compose solution, container names should resolve internally to the IP addresses of that Docker container. However I am struggling to get this to work in my current example.

My YAML file is as follows:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  container1:
    container_name: container1
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
    command: powershell -c 'Start-Sleep 50000' # Keep container running

  container2:
    container_name: container2
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
    command: powershell -c 'Start-Sleep 50000' # Keep container running
```

I am launching the solution as follows:

```
docker compose -f docker-compose-test.yml up -d
```

The containers come up and I can exec into `container1`. I can also ping `container2` from `container1` using its IPv4 address or its container ID:

```
C:\>ping 172.26.39.147

Pinging 172.26.39.147 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.26.39.147: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.26.39.147: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.26.39.147: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.26.39.147: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 172.26.39.147:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms

C:\>ping 4e9c7b16d85a

Pinging 4e9c7b16d85a.local [fe80::39dd:5f1c:d4d5:36fd%4] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::39dd:5f1c:d4d5:36fd%4: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::39dd:5f1c:d4d5:36fd%4: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::39dd:5f1c:d4d5:36fd%4: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::39dd:5f1c:d4d5:36fd%4: time=1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::39dd:5f1c:d4d5:36fd%4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
```

However, if I attempt to ping `container2` using the name 'container2', the host is not found:

```
C:\>ping container2
Ping request could not find host container2. Please check the name and try again.
```

My understanding is that, within Docker compose, the container name **should** resolve to the IP address of the container, however for Windows containers I'm struggling to get this to work. Interestingly, if I run the equivalent example using Linux containers (swapping out the `image` in the YAML file above simply for the latest `nginx` image), resolution via container name **does** work as expected. All I have changed in the Windows example is the container image that I am using, and the PowerShell `command` to keep the containers running.

Am I missing something obvious? Or is there some nuance of Docker compose on Windows containers that I'm failing to understand?

**EDIT**

I have since found that manually configuring the `hostname` of the containers (in other words, overriding the container ID) achieves the result that I am after:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  container1:
    container_name: container1
    hostname: container1
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
    command: powershell -c 'Start-Sleep 50000' # Keep container running

  container2:
    container_name: container2
    hostname: container2
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
    command: powershell -c 'Start-Sleep 50000' # Keep container running
```

Ping result:

```
C:\>ping container2

Pinging container2.local [fe80::2394:2514:5f1f:f4e0%4] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::2394:2514:5f1f:f4e0%4: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::2394:2514:5f1f:f4e0%4: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::2394:2514:5f1f:f4e0%4:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

I would still like to understand why the original solution doesn't work, though. My feeling is that the workaround oughtn't be necessary

Comment: "My understanding is that, within Docker compose, the container name should resolve to the IP address of the container" only if they're on the same network.

Comment: @erik258 both containers are on the default network created by Docker:
`C:\> docker network inspect -f '{{range .Containers}}{{.Name}} {{end}}' docker-examples_default` produces output: `container1 container2`
I did also experiment with manually provisioning the network, but no difference